# Parallels Shared Folder + IIS 8 = really slow page loads

Tags: performance, parallels

I've recently switched over to using a MAC as my main computer, but I am a .NET developer so require the ability to use Visual Studio and IIS so have setup a VM for this. I've got everything working as I like except one thing, and that is terrible shared folder performance when connecting IIS with the \psf\ network share.

I've done a lot of reading, and tried a few things, but none of it seems to be speeding up the file share. Anyone got any ideas on how I can improve the performance of the share? (Some friends of mine with the same setup say they don't have the same performance hit, so am guessing it's something wrong with my config?)

This is how i'm setup so far:

MBP 13" (Mid 2012)
SSD 480GB
OSX 10.8.4
Parallels Desktop 8 for Mac (8.0.18494)
Windows 8 Pro
IIS8
ASP.NET 4.5
SQL Express 2008 (Installed on VM with database files on VM)

OSX + Win have same user account setup (with password)
Parallels config:
- CPU Cores: 2
- RAM: 4gb
- Disk Space: 240GB
- Shared folders: Cutom > Documents Read/Write (Accessible in win via \psf\Document)
- Shared profile: off
- SmartMount: off
- Network1: connected, bridged (default adapter), mac address different to macs (as is IP address)
Windows hosts file:
    127.0.0.1   .psf
    127.0.0.1   psf
    127.0.0.1   localhost
CASPOL has been configured to give full trust to \psf* UNC

IIS Website setup:
- Root dir: \psf\Document\MySite
-   Connect as: Same shared user account
-   App pool: ApplicationPoolIdentity
-   Umbraco: v6

Site runs, but experience between 7 to 12 second page loads
Files run locally, speed is acceptable
Run a simple website from network share and speed seemed ok

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the same setup a couple of years ago, but didn't get as far as you. I was running VS2010 and Parallels 6 at the time, but I could never debug an iis site that was located on the psf share, because VS couldn't lock the web.config file. I therefore skipped the idea, and now I run it locally from my Win partition, and any files I need from the psf share, I link. I don't know if that is a viable solution for you.
If not, maybe have a look at your antivirus to see if it scans network traffic

/Bo

Comment: Hi Bo. I've tried running the files in the VM and that works fine, so that will be my last resort, but I'd really like to get the files located in osx to work as I'm intending to do a lot of sharing. Regarding the antivirus, I have tested with it disabled and it still exhibits the same issues. Thanks for your suggestions.